# How to translate "Facéties de Descendre" in the context of a board game?

Tags: traduction

I'd like to translate a card from a French board game. In particular, I'm interested about one of the names of the abilities. Now, I'm not a native English speaker, but I'm pretty sure that the official translation is incomplete and too literate:

- "Humour Noir" was translated to "Black Humour", while I believe the correct phrase would be "Dark Humor".
- "Facéties de Descendre" was translated to "Descendre Pranks". As far as I know, "Descendre" does not function in English. After basic translation, it would seem that it roughly means "pranks in descend".

[image: French and English Djaul cards]

Now, the game is known for its puns and wordplay. I'm pretty sure that the ability name was supposed to sound like "decent pranks" or "indecent pranks", although I'm not sure if it's originally a pun name in French. With that in mind, I have 2 questions:

- What would be the correct literal translation of the ability name?
- In your opinion, what would be the best translation in this context to preserve the pun (if there is one)?

I've thought about "Descend Pranks" or "In-descend Pranks", but I'd like to hear your opinions.

Comment: Your question can't be answered and should be closed : translations **into** French are allowed but not from French to another language. Nevertheless, as I was curious about this question I have a few details concerning it. I can let you have that, if you like, on the chat page (Chez Causette).

Comment: I didn't know about this, sorry. I moved the question to the English Stack Exchange.

Comment: Perfect! I'll have my answer there.

Comment: "Facéties de Descendre" doesn't mean much on its own. It's hard to tell because every word is capitalized but it seems to me that "Descendre" is the name of a place or a person. Is there something like that in the game? It doesn't makes much sense otherwise. And I don't see any pun.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat There is no place or person named "Descendre" as far as I know. Note how "Black Humour" is capitalized similarly. I think it's a translation error.

Comment: If "descendre" is syntactically meant to be an infinitive, that phrase is outright nonsensical in French.